# KSQL query execution fails

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have confluent platform setup on AWS having specifications as two workers, three zookeepers and three brokers.

Can somebody explain why I getting an error while executing the following query in KQL with all the servers up?

`create STREAM SINK_STREAM WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KAFKA_TOPIC='sink-topic') AS select * from YP_USER_STREAM;`

Here YP_USER_STREAM is created as follows :

`CREATE STREAM YP_USER_STREAM (ID INT(11), EMAIL VARCHAR(64)) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='kafkaTopic', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');`

This error is generated at the time of execution of query and at the start of KSQL server :

```
[2019-07-18 09:01:45,766] INFO Retrying admin request due to retriable exception. Retry no: 1 (io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClient:351)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.wrapAndThrow(KafkaFutureImpl.java:45)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl.access$000(KafkaFutureImpl.java:32)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.internals.KafkaFutureImpl$SingleWaiter.await(KafkaFutureImpl.java:89)
```

Can somebody tell me what configuration mistake I would have done?

Comment: That's not an error, it's just an `INFO`. Is there anything else in the query log that indicates a problem? What's the symptom that you're seeing, are you not getting data from your query?

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnknownTopicOrPartitionException: This server does not host this topic-partition.
[2019-07-18 09:15:14,929] ERROR Failed to handle: Command{statement='create STREAM SINK_STREAM_2 WITH (VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KAFKA_TOPIC='sink-topic') AS select * from YP_USER_STREAM;', overwriteProperties={auto.offset.reset=earliest}} (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.computation.StatementExecutor:210)
io.confluent.ksql.exception.KafkaResponseGetFailedException: Failed to Describe Kafka Topics [sink-topic]

Comment: I am not getting any data from the query except the statement "Statement written to command topic"

Comment: you wouldn't get any output of data, because you're just creating a stream. What's the output of `SHOW STREAMS` afterwards?

Comment: where are you running KSQL? Is it also on AWS? or locally?

Comment: I know I won't be getting any data as I am creating stream but the KSQL server shows the error I mentioned above. SHOW STREAMS does not include the stream I tried to create. Basically, my entire confluent platform is on AWS.

Comment: I also want to ask why topic created using ksql getting leader as null :                          
Topic:mysql-debezium-mysql-server.ypdev.yp_user_mask PartitionCount:4 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: mysql-debezium-mysql-server.ypdev.yp_user_mask Partition: 0 Leader: none Replicas: 1002 Isr: 
 Topic: mysql-debezium-mysql-server.ypdev.yp_user_mask Partition: 1 Leader: none Replicas: 0 Isr: 
 Topic: mysql-debezium-mysql-server.ypdev.yp_user_mask Partition: 2 Leader: none Replicas: 1 Isr: 
 Topic: mysql-debezium-mysql-server.ypdev.yp_user_mask Partition: 3 Leader: none Replicas: 2 Isr:

Comment: @RobinMoffatt could you please help?

Comment: Have you configured `advertised.host.name` in `server.properties`?

Comment: I have configured advertised.host.name in server.properties as one of the broker's public IP. I am working on confluent setup so configured this setting worker server.